# How to minimize the following optimization problem: $ \min_{\|v\|=1} \langle v, -Av\rangle $?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

If we have a symmetric matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ge \dots \lambda_n$, we want to minimize the following optimization problem:
$$
\min_{\|v\|=1} \langle v, -Av\rangle
$$

Can we say this problem is equivalent as $$
\max_{\|v\|=1} \langle v, Av\rangle ?
$$
So the result is $\lambda_1$?

Comment: Yes. In particular, we have $\min_{\|v\|=1} \langle v, -Av\rangle = \min_{\|v\|=1} -\langle v, Av\rangle$, and in general $\min_v -f(v) = -\max_v f(v)$.

Comment: Yes, in general $\inf (-S) = - \sup S$. Assuming you ae using the Euclidean norm, of course.

Comment: @BenGrossmann So the result is not $\lambda_1$? But $-\lambda_1$?

Comment: @Hermi That's correct; I missed the last line of your question. Certainly, however, computing $-\lambda_1$ is "equivalent to" computing $\lambda_1$.